# opening folder with VBA with brackets in path

Tags: excel, shell, file, vba

For the last couple of days I have been trying to open a file via VBA using Shell()

My problem is that the path that I have has brackets in the path: c:/xxx/(xxx)/xxx

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

```
Sub OpenMyFolder()

    Dim myFolder As String

    myFolder = "C:\Users\MrSmith\Dropbox (Personal)\Photos\2018"

    myFolder = myFolder & "\Jan"

    Shell "explorer.exe" & " " & myFolder, vbNormalFocus

End Sub
```

Comment: Please provide your code

Comment: Please see code, thank you.

Comment: Excel 2016 works without issues. My guess is that your version of Excel or Windows requires the path to also include quotation marks.

Try this myFolder = """C:\Users\MrSmith\Dropbox (Personal)\Photos\2018"""

Comment: Thank you, it works if I already know the string. What if i need to modify the string on the fly (please see the code above, I made a small change). I can not include "\Jan" in to """ because it will change, it's a variable.

Comment: Thank you, using your logic i just replaced """ with Chr(34). Thank you again for all your help

Answer (score 0):

When passing any path with spaces to Shell you should enclose it in quotes:

```
Sub OpenMyFolder()

    Dim myFolder As String

    myFolder = "C:\Users\MrSmith\Dropbox (Personal)\Photos\2018"

    myFolder = myFolder & "\Jan"

    Shell "explorer.exe """ & myFolder & """", vbNormalFocus

End Sub
```

Quotes in a VBA string should be doubled-up to escape them (i.e. so the quotes are not interpreted as the beginning /ending of the string)